# Transfering text from floating window to messaging app

Tags: android

I have an Edit box in my floating window . I am launching the floating window over messaging app . I want that whatever i write in the edit box on floating window , I gets reflected in the compose message box of messaging app . Any idea?

Comment: What is a floating window????

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to get the instance of your floating window then create public methods that writes whatever you want to write:

```
// Note that getInstance here is something that you make how you do it is up to you
FloatingWindow.getInstance().setMessage("Hello World");
```

If you can't get the instance for some reason you can register custom BroadcastRecievers when you create your FloatingWindow:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("com.example.floatingWindow.setMessage");
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.equals("com.example.floatingWindow.setMessage") ){
            writeYourMessage(intent.getStringExtra("message"));
        }
    }
}, intentFilter);
```

Then send your message from anywhere with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.floatingWindow.setMessage");
intent.putExtra("message", "Hello");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: I can get the text written in the floating window but how i will write the text in the messaging app running with it ?

Comment: ohh ooops I'll just delete this I think I misread ahha sorry bout that. Did you mean manipulate the messaging app that is not yours?

Comment: No..its just like tranfering text from floating window to any other app(eg : messaging)

Comment: ahh then the broadcast reciever answer can still be valid if you have control to the messaging app.

Comment: Faisal bhai u right.. i can do this at framework level . But i dont want my app to be independent and work on any device . So i dont want to make changes in the core messaging app .

Comment: This may be impossible since it looks like you want to do actions on an app that may or may not have the intent filters to do what you want. What you can do unofficially is look at logs if you have seen the same actions done by other apps and see what broadcast they are sending to do it.